# Change working directory of a imported module

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am having trouble with some modules i want to import, so let's me put a sample to explain better.

```
proyect/
  helpers/
    config.py
  locations/
    loc1.py
  pages/
    page1.py
  Tools/
    myTool.py
```

So whats happening is that in `myTool.py` i'm importing `page1.py` that import from `loc1.py`. to do that i'm appendind '../ ' to `sys.path`. The problem is that in loc1 is imported `config.py` and initialize, when it do that it working dir is TOols/  but i need it to be my proyect dir.

Comment: Don't get it, can u try specify more your problem?

Comment: An less painful path might be to make all those directories proper modules (`__init__.py`), use [relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and [run `myTool.py` as a module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/).

Answer (score 1):

Modules don't have working dirs, only the program as a whole does.

You should add the proyect dir to sys.path at the start of the script, then import loc1 from locations.